# splitting a python list into sublists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list  that I want to split into multiple sublists

```
acq=['A1', 'A2', 'D', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'D', 'A6']
ll=[]
for k,v in enumerate(acq):
    if v == 'D':
        continue    # continue here
    ll.append(v)
    print(ll)
```

Above solution give gives an expanded appended list, which is not what I am looking for. My desired solution is:

```
['A1', 'A2']
['A3', 'A4', 'A5']
['A6']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

acq = ["A1", "A2", "D", "A3", "A4", "A5", "D", "A6"]

for v, g in groupby(acq, lambda v: v == "D"):
    if not v:
        print(list(g))
```

Prints:

```py
['A1', 'A2']
['A3', 'A4', 'A5']
['A6']
```

Answer (score 0):

No additional Library, and return a list of lists:

```
acq=['A1', 'A2', 'D', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'D', 'A6']
all_list=[]
ll=[]
for i in acq:
    
    if i == 'D':
        all_list.append(ll)
        ll=[]
        continue
    ll.append(i)
    
all_list.append(ll)
print(*all_list,sep='\n')
```

print:

```
['A1', 'A2']
['A3', 'A4', 'A5']
['A6']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
acq=['A1', 'A2', 'D', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'D', 'A6']
ll=[]
temp=[]
for k,v in enumerate(acq):
    if v == 'D':
        ll.append(temp)
        temp=[]
        continue    # continue here
    temp.append(v)
l1.append(temp)
print(ll)
```